# Aging A Lot Faster

Tags: time

The day before yesterday, I was 20 years old, and next year I will turn 23. What day is it today?

Note: This is not `lateral-thinking`, and the solution is real and makes sense.

Comment: shouldn't it be 22?

Comment: I was *sure* this must be a duplicate, but apparently it hasn't been asked here before!

Comment: @skan That's why this riddle is so amazing.

Comment: @LifesavingLinen why the bounty? 1065 views and not enough attention? :/....like I'm perfectly okay with it because of the rep gain :D but like srsly?

Comment: My daughter's birthday is New Years Eve and we comment along these lines every year ("the day before yesterday she was 2, next year she'll 5!" etc. She's only 6 now and doesn't get it yet.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The day is

> January 1st

Reasoning:

> My birthday is on December 31st. And therefore yesterday, I turned 21. I was 20 the day BEFORE yesterday, though. This year on December 31st, I will turn 22, and next year I will turn 23.

Classic Mind Puzzle :) My fav <3

Comment: Beaten by seconds!